# How to show contents at first site load when LoadPostsOnScroll=TRUE and PostPerPage=10 while PauseLoadingOfPosts=TRUE using Ajax load more plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have been using for this plugin now and I liked it. Only, there is a little thing that I wanted it to work but seems the plugin can't do it by adjusting its settings. I think somewhere in its code that should be manipulated. I want the plugin to load first the first 10 post contents before using the load more or show more button. What happens is, even I set the **load posts on scroll** to **TRUE** and **post per page** to **10** when the **Pause Loading of Posts (Do not load posts until user clicks load button.)** is set to **TRUE**, the post contents are not loaded at first load of the home page. I want the plugin to appear the first 10 post contents as what I have set in accordance to the setting adjustment I have just mentioned **(load posts on scroll=true,post per page=10,Pause Loading of Posts=true)**. How can I do this? See the images below.Please help. Thanks a lot.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Output:**

[image]

The output shows the contents are not loaded at first. It should have loaded 10 post contents to be showed first before clicking the older post/show more button. How can I do this?

Comment: try `Pause Loading of Posts=false`

Comment: Yes it loads contents but I wanted it to click the button first and not to load automatically